# How to continuously do speech recognition of a continuously increasing audio file using python?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, asterisk, ivr

I have a project in which I want to convert an audio file during the live call into text continuously.

Actually, I get the recording of the callee only during live call and I want to recognize whenever he speaks during that live call. Remember that I just want to recognize what the callee is saying until he stops saying that sentence(s) but not what he has already said before during that live call. I want to do all this using python or php. Python is a better option. Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: Is your issue with getting the audio, transmitting the audio, processing the audio into text or all 3? Have you looked into MRCP solutions? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Media_Resource_Control_Protocol

Comment: My issue is with processing the audio into text.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this with ARI. There is a [python library for it](https://github.com/asterisk/ari-py). Here's how I would approach it:

1. In dialplan, put call in Stasis to start ARI. See [docs](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=29395573)
2. [Start recording the channel](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Channels+REST+API#Asterisk13ChannelsRESTAPI-record) (not the bridge). This way you only get their audio.
3. You can optionally watch for [ChannelTalkingStarted](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Channels+REST+API#Asterisk13ChannelsRESTAPI-record) and ChannelTalkingFinished events to save timestamps that they are speaking if you are making some kind of log.
4. Stream the recording file up to [Google Speech API](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/streaming-recognize) (or similar), and process near real-time results in Python.

   - You could alternatively use talking started/finished events to "slice" up the recording (with `sox`) and transcribe each piece during the call if you don't need immediate results.
5. With the flexibility of ARI (instead of dialplan), you can easily send the text results out to another app you make via an API.